# python string encoding for Requests call to Google Maps API

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3, python-requests

I am trying to make a simple reverse geocoding call to the Google Maps API...

```
lat = 40.714224
long = -73.961452
urlparams = {'LatLng': str(lat)+","+str(long),
             'key': dsc.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY
            }
burl = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json'
r = requests.get(burl, params=urlparams)
```

This fails because the "," is being translated to %2C:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?LatLng=40.714224%2C-73.961452&key=dsc.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY
{'error_message': "Invalid request. Missing the 'address', 'components', 'latlng' or 'place_id' parameter.", 'results': [], 'status': 'INVALID_REQUEST'}
```

I have tried a bunch of tricks (convert to bytes, bytearrays, encode("utf-8")) to make this work but to no avail.... I am aware of the urllib module with its parse.quote, etc. methods but must I switch?

Comment: really not sure if it will work or but have you tested changing `","` to `r","`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Apparently the parameter names are case sensitive. You will also need to use HTTPS. Here is a working code:

```
lat = 40.714224
long = -73.961452
urlparams = {
             'latlng': "{},{}".format(lat, long),
             'key': dsc.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY
            }
burl = 'https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json'
r = requests.get(burl, params=urlparams)
```

Original (wrong) answer: Would using an array instead of a string work?

```
lat = 40.714224
long = -73.961452
urlparams = {'LatLng': [str(lat), str(long)],
             'key': dsc.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY
            }
burl = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json'
r = requests.get(burl, params=urlparams)
```

Comment: Alas, no, that gets me "LatLng=40.714224&LatLng=-73.961452"

Comment: Yes, I found that too! Thank you. I got focused on the wrong error.

Answer (score 0):

Giving up. Using pygeocoder instead:

```
my_geocoder = Geocoder(api_key=dsc.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY)
results = my_geocoder.reverse_geocode(lat, long)
```